# Audio doesn't work on iMac 20" early 2008 with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, mac, apple

I tried with several guides, but no one worked out.

The last one was http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3697702&postcount=5.
It seemed to be good, but when i run the `./configure` command it says:

```
checking for GCC version... ./configure: eval: line 4919: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./configure: eval: line 4919: `my_compiler_version=4.6.3-1ubuntu5)'
```

How can I get my audio working?

Comment: do you have gcc? `sudo apt-get install gcc` to install it

Comment: I have gcc already installed. I think there is a error in the patch...

Comment: I found this info on my audio harware with `lspci -v` :

  `00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00a0
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
 Memory at d0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel`

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the latest DKMS. This will resolve your issues (as it did mine with my Macbook Pro 17" early 2008).

Here is a link: [alsa-hda-dkms_0.201210170702~precise1_all.deb](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+files/alsa-hda-dkms_0.201210170702~precise1_all.deb)